# Alternatives to multiple ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm tired of multiple `ifelse` statements in R. I know there is a function with name `switch` but could not figured out how to use if the for following example.

```
set.seed(12345)
Y <- runif(n=100, min=0, max=50)

ifelse(
    test = Y < 5
  , yes  = "A"
  , no   =  ifelse(
         test = Y < 10
       , yes  = "B"
       , no = "C"
       )
    )
```

Output:

```
  [1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [19] "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C"
 [37] "C" "C" "C" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "A" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [55] "C" "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [73] "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "B" "C" "C" "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A"
 [91] "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "C"
```

### Edited

If I have the following code, then what would be the better alternative for `ifelse` statement?

```
set.seed(12345)
Y <- runif(n=100, min=0, max=50)

ifelse(
    test = Y < 5
  , yes  = -5
  , no   =  ifelse(
         test = Y < 10
       , yes  = 0
       , no = 5
       )
    )
```

Comment: You could take a look at `?cut`

Comment: maybe you getting tired is partially due to typing the argument names `test, yes, no`. These are not needed, as in `ifelse(Y<5,"A",ifelse(Y<10, "B","C"))`

Comment: @flodel: Yes, you right!!! But good to have.

Comment: On `cut`'s concept, see, also, `?findInterval` that -if suits your needs- can be faster given it produces a less "tidy" output than `cut`. `LETTERS[findInterval(Y, c(-Inf, 5, 10, Inf))]`.

Comment: @alexis_lax: `findInterval(Y, c(5,10))` is sufficient here (no need for infinities), although a `+1` is necessary to make them into the right indices into `LETTERS`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`switch` isn't really meant for something like this, `cut` is better:

```
cut(Y,c(-Inf,5,10,Inf),labels=LETTERS[1:3],right=FALSE)
  [1] C C C C C B C C C C A B C A C C C C B C C C C C C C C C C C C A B C C C C
 [38] C C B C C C C C C A A A C C C C C C C C A C C C C C C C C C B C C C C C C
 [75] A C C C C B C C A A B C C C C A C C A C C C C C A C
Levels: A B C
```

Comment: Thanks @James for your answer. If I need numeric values from cut rather than letters.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the argument `labels=FALSE` will give the underlying integer codes rather than the factor.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You can just subset the vector of choices by the output of `cut`, ie `c(-5,0,5)[cut(...)]`, or use the `findInterval` approach suggested by @alexis_laz

Comment: @jbest I'm not sure what you mean, and I think you are drifting away from the original question. Can you ask as a separate question and provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way based on logical and mathematical operations (addressing your edit):

```
5 * ((Y >= 10) - (Y < 5))

 [1]  5  5  5  5  5  0  5  5  5  5 -5  0  5 -5  5  5  5  5  0  5  5  5
[23]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 -5  0  5  5  5  5  5  5  0  5  5  5  5
[45]  5  5 -5 -5 -5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 -5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
[67]  5  0  5  5  5  5  5  5 -5  5  5  5  5  0  5  5 -5 -5  0  5  5  5
[89]  5 -5  5  5 -5  5  5  5  5  5 -5  5
```